# Trying to make the answer randomly generated after retry in C#

Tags: c#, random

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   

            int num1 = int.Parse(args[0]);
            int num2 = int.Parse(args[1]);            
            bool GameOver = false;
            int turn = 3;
            Random random = new Random();
            int answer = random.Next(num1, num2);        
            // string input = "";

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, welcome to the guess a number challenge");

            while (!GameOver)
            {
                if (turn != 0)
                {                    
                    turn--;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Please Select number between {num1} to {num2}:");                    
                    int SelectedNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (SelectedNumber < answer && SelectedNumber >= num1)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Almost there, just the number is too small\n");
                    } else if (SelectedNumber > answer && SelectedNumber <= num2)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Your number is too big\n");
                    } else if(SelectedNumber == answer)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("CONGRATULATIONS!!!! You guess it right\n");
                        GameOver = true;
                        retry();
                    } else
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Your number is out of range\n");
                    }
                } else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"GAME OVER!!!! The answer is {answer}");
                    GameOver = true;
                    retry();
                }

                void retry() {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Would you like to retry? Y/N");
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    string ConsoleInput = input.ToLower();
                    if(ConsoleInput == "y")
                    {
                        GameOver = false;
                        turn = 3;
                    } else if(ConsoleInput == "n")
                    {
                        GameOver = true;
                    } else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                        retry();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello all, just want to ask a question.
I tried to build "guess a number" game in terminal, where player has to guess a number based on the number range given.
I tried to make the *answer* randomly generated, thus the Random class.
and the answer will be randomized after retry.
The problem is, after each retry, the *answer* is still the same.
I am not sure where did I did wrong.
Thanks for the help, and sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Add `answer = random.Next(num1, num2 + 1);` after `if(ConsoleInput == "y")`, to generate a new `answer` it the player wants to retry. Note that the upper bound is exclusive. So, if the initial arguments are `1` and `10`, `random.Next(num1, num2)` will generate numbers in the range `1 - 9`.

Comment: You need another loop outside `while (!GameOver)` to re-run the game in case of retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i edited out your code

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter num1");
            int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter num2");
            int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bool GameOver = false;
            int turn = 3;
            Random random = new Random();
            int answer = random.Next(num1, num2);
            // string input = "";

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, welcome to the guess a number challenge");

            while (!GameOver)
            {
                if (turn != 0)
                {
                    turn--;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Please Select number between {num1} to {num2}:");
                    int SelectedNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (SelectedNumber < answer && SelectedNumber >= num1)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Almost there, just the number is too small\n");
                    }
                    else if (SelectedNumber > answer && SelectedNumber <= num2)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Your number is too big\n");
                    }
                    else if (SelectedNumber == answer)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("CONGRATULATIONS!!!! You guess it right\n");
                        GameOver = true;
                        retry();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Your number is out of range\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"GAME OVER!!!! The answer is {answer}");
                    GameOver = true;
                    retry();
                }

                void retry()
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Would you like to retry? Y/N");
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    string ConsoleInput = input.ToLower();
                    if (ConsoleInput == "y")
                    {
                        answer = random.Next(num1, num2);
                        GameOver = false;
                        turn = 3;
                    }
                    else if (ConsoleInput == "n")
                    {
                        GameOver = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                        retry();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked. thanks a bunch, mate.

actually, the reason why I put the value of num1 with args[] is so that there is no need for me to input the range. Just run the program with set parameters and let the player guess the answer.

anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need an outside loop in order to start a new game after the end:

See below a skeleton program with the necessary control flow.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool retry = false;
        do
        {
            // start of game
            bool gameOver = false;
            int turn = 3;
            do
            {
                // game here
                // set gameOver when guess is corrent
                turn--;
            } while (turn>0 && !gameOver);
            // post game scores
            // ask to retry
        } while (retry);
        // end here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, mate. I never thought of using do-while loop. Will try to use it after this.